# awk: searching log on the multiple patterns

Tags: bash, awk, full-text-search

I am dealing with the analysis of the data in the many separate log filles.
This is the format of each log

```
Finding intramodel H-bonds
Constraints relaxed by 0.6 angstroms and 20 degrees
Models used:
    1.1 SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb
    1.2 SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb
    1.3 SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb
    1.4 SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb
    1.5 SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb
    1.6 SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb
    1.7 SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb
    1.8 SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb
    1.9 SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb
    1.10 SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb
    1.11 SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb
    1.12 SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb
    1.13 SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb
    1.14 SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb
    1.15 SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb
    1.16 SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb
    1.17 SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb
    1.18 SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb
    1.19 SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb
    1.20 SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb
    1.21 SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb
    1.22 SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb
    1.23 SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb
    1.24 SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb

17 H-bonds
H-bonds (donor, acceptor, hydrogen, D..A dist, D-H..A dist):
SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.1/? HIE 163 NE2   SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.1/A LIG 888 O2   SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.1/? HIE 163 HE2    3.250  2.448
SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.1/? GLU 166 N     SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.1/A LIG 888 O1   SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.1/? GLU 166 H      2.817  2.027
SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.2/? THR 26 N      SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.2/A LIG 888 N2   SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.2/? THR 26 H       3.453  2.470
SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.2/? HIE 163 NE2   SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.2/A LIG 888 O2   SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.2/? HIE 163 HE2    3.269  2.495
SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.2/? GLU 166 N     SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.2/A LIG 888 O1   SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.2/? GLU 166 H      3.555  2.634
SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.4/? GLU 166 N     SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.4/A LIG 888 O1   SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.4/? GLU 166 H      3.622  2.743
SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.5/? GLU 166 N     SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.5/A LIG 888 O1   SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.5/? GLU 166 H      2.797  1.790
SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.10/? GLU 166 N    SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.10/A LIG 888 O1  SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.10/? GLU 166 H     3.780  2.783
SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.12/? GLU 166 N    SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.12/A LIG 888 O1  SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.12/? GLU 166 H     3.273  2.541
SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.14/? HIE 163 NE2  SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.14/A LIG 888 O2  SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.14/? HIE 163 HE2   3.389  2.556
SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.15/? ASN 142 ND2  SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.15/A LIG 888 O2  SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.15/? ASN 142 2HD2  3.067  2.303
SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.15/? GLY 143 N    SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.15/A LIG 888 N2  SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.15/? GLY 143 H     2.962  2.016
SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.16/? GLU 166 N    SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.16/A LIG 888 O1  SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.16/? GLU 166 H     2.926  1.930
SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.19/? GLN 189 NE2  SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.19/A LIG 888 O1  SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.19/? GLN 189 1HE2  3.026  2.212
SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.22/? GLY 143 N    SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.22/A LIG 888 O1  SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.22/? GLY 143 H     2.855  1.848
SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.22/? HIE 163 NE2  SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.22/A LIG 888 O2  SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.22/? HIE 163 HE2   3.345  2.400
SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.24/? GLN 189 NE2  SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.24/A LIG 888 O1  SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.24/? GLN 189 1HE2  2.893  2.286
```

I need to consider each line after the string

```
H-bonds (donor, acceptor, hydrogen, D..A dist, D-H..A dist):
```

From the rest lines I need to check whether three keywords:

```
GLU 166
HIE 163
THR 26
```

are present in the same index (defined as 1.1 , 1.2 ... 1.24) and then print the name of the log + the ID of the index value (in the second column).
In the log, the index value is 1.2 since the three keywords are:

```
SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.2/? THR 26 N      SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.2/A LIG 888 N2   SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.2/? THR 26 H       3.453  2.470
SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.2/? HIE 163 NE2   SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.2/A LIG 888 O2   SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.2/? HIE 163 HE2    3.269  2.495
SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.2/? GLU 166 N     SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.2/A LIG 888 O1   SarsCov2_mol30_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.2/? GLU 166 H      3.555  2.634
```

so the expected output should be:

```
log_name.log the patterns are found in the #1.2!
```

**UPDATE:** Finally in some tricky cases one of the search patterns may be located in different parts of the string (always preserving the same format), for example in the below example the pattern GLU 166 of the last string is located in another column compared to two other patterns belong to index #1.3

```
43 H-bonds
H-bonds (donor, acceptor, hydrogen, D..A dist, D-H..A dist):
SarsCov2_06I_nsp5holoHIE_rep2.pdb #1.1/? THR 26 N      SarsCov2_06I_nsp5holoHIE_rep2.pdb #1.1/A LIG 888 O    SarsCov2_06I_nsp5holoHIE_rep2.pdb #1.1/? THR 26 H       3.355  2.554
SarsCov2_06I_nsp5holoHIE_rep2.pdb #1.1/? GLU 166 N     SarsCov2_06I_nsp5holoHIE_rep2.pdb #1.1/A LIG 888 O    SarsCov2_06I_nsp5holoHIE_rep2.pdb #1.1/? GLU 166 H      3.071  2.100
SarsCov2_06I_nsp5holoHIE_rep2.pdb #1.1/A LIG 888 N     SarsCov2_06I_nsp5holoHIE_rep2.pdb #1.1/? THR 26 O     SarsCov2_06I_nsp5holoHIE_rep2.pdb #1.1/A LIG 888 H      3.463  2.657
SarsCov2_06I_nsp5holoHIE_rep2.pdb #1.2/? HIE 163 NE2   SarsCov2_06I_nsp5holoHIE_rep2.pdb #1.2/A LIG 888 O    SarsCov2_06I_nsp5holoHIE_rep2.pdb #1.2/? HIE 163 HE2    3.019  2.147
SarsCov2_06I_nsp5holoHIE_rep2.pdb #1.2/A LIG 888 N     SarsCov2_06I_nsp5holoHIE_rep2.pdb #1.2/? PHE 140 O    SarsCov2_06I_nsp5holoHIE_rep2.pdb #1.2/A LIG 888 H      3.169  2.591
SarsCov2_06I_nsp5holoHIE_rep2.pdb #1.3/? THR 26 N      SarsCov2_06I_nsp5holoHIE_rep2.pdb #1.3/A LIG 888 S    SarsCov2_06I_nsp5holoHIE_rep2.pdb #1.3/? THR 26 H       3.666  2.696
SarsCov2_06I_nsp5holoHIE_rep2.pdb #1.3/? HIE 163 NE2   SarsCov2_06I_nsp5holoHIE_rep2.pdb #1.3/A LIG 888 N    SarsCov2_06I_nsp5holoHIE_rep2.pdb #1.3/? HIE 163 HE2    2.959  2.050
SarsCov2_06I_nsp5holoHIE_rep2.pdb #1.3/A LIG 888 N     SarsCov2_06I_nsp5holoHIE_rep2.pdb #1.3/? GLU 166 O    SarsCov2_06I_nsp5holoHIE_rep2.pdb #1.3/A LIG 888 H      3.118  2.200
```

I've tried to loop each log using simple bash workflow with awk code that looked for 1 pattern but could not do it with three patterns belonged to the same index #

```
for log in /logs/*hbondsALL_rep"${i}".log; do
  log_name=$(basename "$log" .log | cut -d'_' -f 2)
  # search only one pattern GLU 166
  i=$(awk -vn=1 '/GLU 166/ {gsub(/.*\.|\/\?/,"",$2); n=$2; exit} END {print n}' $log)
  # insert here alternative search solution which check the patterns!
  # and find the index {i} in the log
  # log_name.log the patterns are found in the # {i} 
done
```

may I use sed or AWK for such pattern based search intergrated in bash?

Comment: done! I just indicated awk sollution

Comment: Are (index,keyword) pairs unique within a file?

Comment: Actually, in each log we do have each keyword on separate string paired to the index ID. so the goal is just to print the first index ID contained all three keywords ensemble (they should be on three separate strings)

Comment: Do you want only files in which ALL THREE patterns are found within a single index? Could they appear in more than one index, and if so, do you want every index where they match?

Comment: That's absolutely right I need to print the log names where ALL three patterns are found within a single index! In the case if there are these three patterns in two different indexes (of the same log) i need just to print the number of the first index where all three patterns were found!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- lines of interest have three separate index/keyword tuples we need to compare (fields `#2 / #3 / #4`, fields `#7 / #8 / #9`, fields `#12 / #13 / #14`)
- for a given line of interest the numeric portion of the three indexes (ie, fields `#2`, `#7` and `#12`) is always the same (eg, `#1.2/?` is equivalent to `#1.2/A`)
- within a file an index/keyword pair (eg, `#1.2 / GLU 1661`) may occur more than once
- within a file all lines of interest are sorted by index (eg, `#1.1` before `#1.2` before `#1.3` ...)

One `awk` idea that allows the user to supply a list of keywords via a `bash` variable:

```
keywords='GLU 166,HIE 163,THR 26'

awk -v keywords="${keywords}" '

function print_match() {

    if (length(found) == key_cnt) {                    # if all keys were found then ...
       print FILENAME,"the patterns are found in the",ndx "!"
    #  found_hb=0                                      # uncomment to  print only the first matching index in a file
    }
    delete found                                       # clear found[] array
}

BEGIN      { key_cnt=split(keywords,a,",")             # parse input parameter "keywords"
             for (i=1;i<=key_cnt;i++)                  # convert to an associative array where keys are the array indices
                 keys[a[i]]
             delete found                              # declare to awk that found[] is an array
           }

FNR==1     { print_match()                             # new file? flush previous index details and ... 
             found_hb=0                                # disable testing for keywords
           }
/^H-bonds/ { found_hb=1; next }                        # enable testing for keywords
found_hb   { split($2,a,"/")                           # obtain numeric portion of index and ...
             new_ndx=a[1]                              # store in variable new_ndx
             if (new_ndx != ndx) {                     # if this is a new index then ...
                print_match()                          # flush previous index details and ...
                ndx=new_ndx                            # make note of new index
             }
             for (i=3;i<=13;i=i+5) {                   # loop through keywords: fields #3/#4, #8/#9, #13/#14
                 key=$i FS $(i+1)
                 if (key in keys)                      # if we find a match then ...
                    found[key]                         # create an entry in the found[] array
             }
           }
END        { print_match() }                           # flush last index details
' test.log
```

**NOTE:** for a large number of keywords (to search for) I'd probably opt for storing them in a file which in turn would require a few tweaks of this code to load said file (of keywords) into the `keys[]` associative array, but that's for another day and a different Q&A session ...

---

Taking for a test drive ...

**NOTE:** `test.log` is a copy of OP's original input file while `test.log2` is a copy of OP's 2nd/UPDATE input file

When `keywords='GLU 166,HIE 163,THR 26'`:

```
test.log the patterns are found in the #1.2!
test.log2 the patterns are found in the #1.3!
```

When `keywords='GLU 166,HIE 163'`:

```
test.log the patterns are found in the #1.1!
test.log the patterns are found in the #1.2!           # does not print if the 'found_hb=0' line (in the print_match() function) is uncommented
test.log2 the patterns are found in the #1.3!
```

When `keywords='ASN 142,GLY 143'`:

```
test.log the patterns are found in the #1.15!
```

When `keywords='ASN 142,HIE 163'`:

```
           <<<=== no output
```

Comment: Thank you very much for such elegant sollution! Two questions: is it possible modify the first assumption (which sometimes may be ignored), e.g. in two logs I have a situation when the same keyword belongs two times to the same index (but ain't no the 3rd keyword), and the script find this ID. E.g. it was in the case of duplication of such line  #1.3/? HIE 163 NE2 would it be possible just skip the duplicators??

Comment: Also I added a case in my first topic which does not matched by your script, which I find very fast compared to others propositions :-)

Comment: @JamesStarlight answer has been updated to address the latest changes to requirements and/or sample data

Comment: many thanks for these kind corrections! it works very well, i've just accepted. Just a minor question:   now it prints the index in the format like #1.14 (taking it directly from the log file), would it be possible just to print the second part of the index (after the dot) like simply "14" ?

Comment: change `split($2,a,"/")` to `split($2,a,"[./]")` and `new_ndx=a[1]` to `new_ndx=a[2]`

Answer (score 1):

An `awk` solution could be:

```
awk -F '[ /]' -v keyword_list='GLU 166,HIE 163,THR 26' '
    BEGIN {
        n=split(keyword_list, a, ",")
        for (i=1; i<=n; ++i) keywords[a[i]]
    }
    FNR==1 { in_roi=0; delete found }
    /^H-bonds/ { in_roi=1; next }
    in_roi && !found[$2] && ((kw=$4 " " $5) in keywords) {
        found[$2 " " kw]
        found[$2]=1
        for (kw in keywords) {
            if (!($2 " " kw in found)) { found[$2]=0; next }
        }
        print FILENAME ": the patterns are found in the " $2
    }
' *.log
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very much! I've just tested it and generally it works BUT in one file it could find the ID where only two patterns were located (GLU and HIE but not THR). Does it mean that the script also consider possibility with fewer patterns? Also would it be possible to specify patterns like (GLU 166|HIE 163| THR 26)

Comment: @JamesStarlight  Could you please write the indexes and keywords (not the whole lines, just indexes and keywords: #1.2 GLU, #1.2 THR, #1.2 GLY etc., for instance) where the script went wrong.

Comment: printed the index 1.4 where only two patters were presented SarsCov2_Y6J_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.4/? HIE 163 NE2   SarsCov2_Y6J_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.4/A LIG 888 N     SarsCov2_Y6J_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.4/? HIE 163 HE2    3.106  2.112
SarsCov2_Y6J_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.4/? HIE 163 NE2   SarsCov2_Y6J_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.4/A LIG 888 N     SarsCov2_Y6J_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.4/? HIE 163 HE2    3.269  2.442
SarsCov2_Y6J_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.4/? GLU 166 N     SarsCov2_Y6J_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.4/A LIG 888 O     SarsCov2_Y6J_nsp5holoHIE_rep1.pdb #1.4/? GLU 166 H      3.588  2.599

Comment: sorry i could coppy the whole lines only with the pattern #1.4 so ain't no pattern with THR !

Comment: @JamesStarlight There are two lines with the same (index,keyword) pairs, that is, (#1.4,HIE). This condition is against the assumption that (index,keyword) pairs are unique within a file. Unfortunately this script as-is won't work correctly on these conditions. I will edit the answer later.

Comment: you AWK version seems to work. The second SED version writes the log_name instead of index, logname.log: the patterns found in the logname.pdb

Comment: @JamesStarlight Strange. Could you please retry the second sed version? I've just done a small update.

Comment: still the same: it find the logs with all three patterns, but however print additionally 10 logs without indicating the IDs where the three patterns are not present

Comment: @JamesStarlight For the moment, it is impossible for me to detect where the script went wrong without having the exact file you've tested. I'm going to delete the sed versions from the answer.

Comment: that's right, thank you for the AWK version. I will test all of them propose in the topic in order that I could understand which one is better. BTW  may you please precise if your AWK version would work with the keyworlds defined as the shell variable which creates for loop? e.g. keywords='GLU 166,HIE 163,THR 26' and then in the awk part, awk -v keywords="${keywords}"

Comment: @JamesStarlight I've added a second awk version.

Comment: thank you! I am going to do the tests. What I could find instantly that for some logs it print information two times (for the same ID), e.g. test_rep1.log: the patterns are found in the #1.2
test_rep1.log: the patterns are found in the #1.2

Comment: @JamesStarlight I've edited it again. Could you please test it.

Comment: Hey, i've just finished tests of your cool AWK code. Basically it works when all three pateerns are located in three different strings belong to the same #ID (this is correct!) but it does not see a pattern located in another column (please see my updated example in the first post).

Answer (score 1):

Using the example log you gave above, and somehat simplistic assumptions -
If what you want is any file in which any of the patterns match, here's one solution:

```
$: awk '/ GLU 166 | HIE 163 | THR 26 /{ gsub("[/?]+","!",$2); print FILENAME" the patterns are found in the "$2; exit; }' log
log the patterns are found in the #1.1!
```

If you only want files and indexes where ALL the patterns are found on a given index, that's a little trickier, but still not so bad.

```
$: awk '/ GLU 166 | HIE 163 | THR 26 / { 
          if ( hit[$2] ~ " "$3$4" " ) { next; } else {  hit[$2]=" "hit[$2]$3$4" " } }
        END{ for (ndx in hit) {
          if ( hit[ndx] ~ / GLU166 / && hit[ndx] ~ / HIE163 / && hit[ndx] ~ / THR26 / ) { 
            gsub("[/?]+","!",ndx); 
            print FILENAME" the patterns are found in the "ndx } } }' log
log the patterns are found in the #1.2!
```

This will also be much faster on log files of any size than a shell script, as all the logic is encapsulated in a single invocation of `awk`. If the files are *really* big, we could add several streamlining improvements.

Passing the list of keys on the command line as an argument:

```
awk -v keywords='GLU 166,HIE 163,THR 26' 'BEGIN {
    split( keywords, keys, ","); gsub( /,/, " | ", keywords ); keywords=" "keywords" "; for ( k in keys ) { gsub( / /, "", keys[k]); }
  } $0 ~ keywords {
    if ( hit[$2] ~ " "$3$4" " ) { next; } else {  hit[$2]=" "hit[$2]$3$4" " }
  } END { for (ndx in hit) { found=1; for (k in keys) { if (hit[ndx] !~ " "keys[k]" ") { found=0; break; } }
    if (found) { gsub(/[/?]+/,"!",ndx); print FILENAME" the patterns are found in the "ndx } }
  }' log?
```

Breaking that out so I can explain with some comments -

```
awk -v keywords='GLU 166,HIE 163,THR 26' 'BEGIN {  # BEFORE reading the files
    split( keywords, keys, ",");                   # split keyswords on commas to array named keys
    gsub( /,/, " | ", keywords );                  # replace commas with spaces and OR pipes build a scan pattern
    keywords=" "keywords" ";                       # add spaces at begin and end to avoid partial matches
    for ( k in keys ) { gsub( / /, "", keys[k]); } # remove spaces inside the keys for consistency
  } $0 ~ keywords {                                # one lines that match one of the keywords
    if ( hit[$2] ~ " "$3$4" " ) { next; }          # skip if we already recorded it
    else {  hit[$2]=" "hit[$2]$3$4" " }            # else record this index has this pattern
  } END {                                          # AFTER reading files
    for (ndx in hit) { found=1;                    # check each index with a hit; assume success
      for (k in keys) {                            # alk each given keyword for this index
        if (hit[ndx] !~ " "keys[k]" ") {           # if any keyword found missing
          found=0;                                 # flag this index as NO MATCH
          break;                                   # and skip further checks
        }
      }
      if (found) {                                          # if all required keywords found on this index
        gsub(/[/?]+/,"!",ndx);                              # correct the output string to your specified format
        print FILENAME" the patterns are found in the "ndx; # and report as specified
      }
    }
  }' *.log
```

With a little more work we could factor the search patterns out to another file, for example. :)

Comment: Thank you so much it works! may you please show the version with the keyworlds used as the shell variables? e.g. keywords='GLU 166,HIE 163,THR 26' and then in the awk part, awk -v keywords="${keywords}"